# Unix shell sh get items from setA that are missing in SetB

Tags: shell, unix

I am using sh Shell (legacy requirements) I have a set like this

```
Set A --> 'A.txt B.txt C.txt D.txt E.txt' 
and another set like 
Set B --> 'A.txt D.txt'
```

If i want to find the items that is present in set B but not in set A

```
setA='A.txt B.txt C.txt D.txt E.txt'
setB='A.txt D.txt'

echo $setA |grep -v -w $setB
```

My attempt does not yeild any results at all

Comment: `printf "%s\n" $setA > tmpA; printf "%s\n" $setB > tmpB; grep -v -w -f tmpB tmpA; rm tmpA tmpB`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
for i in $setB; do 
  if ! echo "$setA" | grep -q "$i";  then 
    echo "$i is not in setA"
  fi
done
```

---

If you have `bash`, you could try this:

```
for i in $setB; do [[ "$setA" =~ "$i" ]] || echo "$i is not in setA"; done
```

The operator `=~` is used to check if an element of `setB` is part of `setA`.

Given the 2 sets, there is no match because you asked *items that are present in set B but not in set A*.

If you extend the `setB` with another element like this:

```
setB='A.txt D.txt F.txt'
```

and then you get

```
$ for i in $setB; do [[ "$setA" =~ "$i" ]] || echo "$i is not in setA"; done
F.txt is not in setA
```

Comment: POSIX shell does not have `[[...]]` or `'=~'`. Bash does, but the question isn't tagged bash. Make sure you clarify the shell. As it is tagged, that solution most likely won't work.

Comment: That's better. I miss the tags sometimes too, but it really helps to try and tailor your answer to the tags. Posting both POSIX and bash solutions is good as long as you make it clear which is which (as you did).